# How to randomize 3 items in 4 boxes?

Tags: php, random

I'm having troubles with this part of my php-course;

*"The webshop has 4 html boxes, there are 3 items in the database.

Fill each box with a random article from the database"*

This was done succesfull with:

`$intRNDx = rand(1, 3);`

(were x is the boxnumber)
And then using $intRNDx in the query.

**THE PROBLEM:**
I can end up with four of the same items.
But if I prevent double-randoms, I would get stuck at item 4.

So, I want 3 different (random) articles and one double item.
But if I compare rand(1) with (for example) rand(2) to prevent doubles.
Then the last two boxes are always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose `random[1,2,3]` - suppose 3 was chosen, next step will be to choose `random[1,2]` now say 1 was chosen, only `2` was left so it's going to be the third article and for the forth:  you have to choose one more but allow repetitions, so now you'll do `random[1,2,3]` again.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you do it this way the last one can be any one of the previous three.

Comment: Tnx, I will give it a try.. Good answer!